# Creating a sequence of numbers for indexing matrices

Tags: r

I am trying to create an index vector for a programming problem. The idea is to be able to index the elements of a matrix so I can replace just these elements with another matrix.

```
nstks<- 2
stk<-1:nstks
nareas<-3
area<-1:nareas
eff<-c(10,10,10)

x<-matrix(1:6,nrow=nstks,ncol=nareas)

h<-matrix(0,nrow=length(eff)+nstks,ncol=nareas)
for(i in 1:nareas) h[i,i]<-1
```

This returns a 5 by 3 matrix with 1s on the diagonal of the first 3 rows. Now I want to replace the 4th and 5th rows with a 2 by 3 matrix returned by another function. One way I figured is to index the h matrix by:

```
hlen<-c(nareas + stk,(nareas+ stk +(nareas +nstks)),(nareas+stk +(nareas+nstks)+(nareas+nstks)))

h[hlen] <- x
```

This replaces the 4,5,9,10,14,15th elements of h with the elements of x in order.

However, I need to make this flexible for differing numbers of nstks and nareas. As an example, for nareas=4 and nstks=3, I need to spit out a vector: c(5,6,7,12,13,14,19,20,21,26,27,28)

To clarify: I need to create the jacobian matrix for a constrained optimization problem. The dimensions of the jacobian vary depending on the number of constraints, and number of variables.  I want to write a function that will give the jacobian matrix for any specified number of dimensions.

The variable is eff, which has the same length as nareas. There are non-negativity constraints on eff, which are reflected in the first nareas*nareas sub matrix being a diagonal identity matrix. The last rows of the matrix reflect the constraint on the number of fish that can be caught, by stock. So, for one stock, there will only be 1 additional row, 2 stocks, 2 additional rows etc. etc.

I need to **replace the elements in these last rows by the elements given by another matrix**. In the example, x is just for illustration. The actual x is given by a function but will have these same dimensions. Does this clarify things?

Any ideas?

Thanks! 
I believe I can use:

```
h[(length(eff)+1): (length(eff)+nstks),1:nareas]<-x
```

I was making it too complicated as usual. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to find the indices for the values you need to replace with a sub-matrix returned from another function, can you not just place in the sub-matrix directly?

E.g. if you have:

```
x <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), ncol=3)
x

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    0
[2,]    1    0    1
```

Identify the part of h you want to drop the sub-matrix in:

```
h[4:5, 1:3] <- x
h

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
[4,]    0    1    0
[5,]    1    0    1
```

Or, if x is a vector,

```
x <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1)
x <- matrix(x, ncol=3, byrow=TRUE)
h[4:5, 1:3] <- x
```

Comment: Ha. I believe this will work- thanks. To make it flexible I could use:

Comment: I hit return by mistake. I edited the op to show what I could do using your logic.

Comment: Cool, nice generalized solution.